# how to insert values into database using ajax in symfony1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, dql

in my project i want to add comments to each post. For inserting comments i am using ajax.
since INSERT statements are not allowed in DQL. How can i insert comments using ajax. any one please help me. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new comment object, fill it with values, then save it.

```
$c = new Comment();
$c->fromArray($request->getParameter("comment"));
$c->save();
```

This is the easiest way. But you should be using a form, so it's also validated:

```
$f = new CommentForm();
$f->bind($request->getParameter($f->getName()));
if ($f->isValid()) {
  $f->save();
}
```

See the [form framework documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/10-Forms) for more info.